# Amazon EC2 Abuse Report

Tags: attack-prevention, ddos, cloud-computing, aws

My company recently received an email from Amazon which notified us of malicious activities occurring on our running EC2 Instance.

The email states:
We observed machines under your control participating in a DDoS attack
targeting Google IPs.

The attack was a UDP amplification attack. In this attack, a UDP-based
service is abused to attack others, wasting your bandwidth and computing
resources.

I am fairly new to all of this stuff in addition to AWS and have no idea as to where to start. What should be the first steps for me to take to mitigate this?

After running the commands from @ximaera

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ davidpham$ ntpdc -nc monlist *ip*
*ip*: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ davidpham$ dig @ip +edns=0 +ignore com ANY

<<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @ip +edns=0 +ignore com ANY
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ davidpham$
```

This was the output I received. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there's a [long list](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-017A) of servers and protocols vulnerable for UDP amplification. A few command line calls to determine the presence of some of the most prominent amplification vectors [might be found here](https://radar.qrator.net/faq). All the commands should better be invoked remotely. E.g. if your server is 192.0.2.1, then, to check for an NTP amplifier, you do

```
ntpdc -nc monlist 192.0.2.1
```

from your laptop or an adjacent datacenter machine.

I'd recommend to check NTP and DNS first, and if there's no match, then to dive into details.

`tcpdump -ni any udp` on the server itself will definitely help you to dive. If you're able to spot any traffic you don't expect to see in the dump, you can then track down the vulnerable application listening on the port seen in the dump by looking (or `grep`ing) at the output of `ss -lpn`.

---

EDIT. So now, as you've provided the IP address of your server, I've been able to check it myself, and it turns out you have a PORTMAP amplifier active:

```
$ rpcinfo -T udp $ip | wc -l
      17
$
```

So you basically needed to go through the rest of the checks past DNS and NTP ones.

The fix is obviously to disable port mapper ([here's how](https://www.bsi.bund.de/EN/Topics/IT-Crisis-Management/CERT-Bund/CERT-Reports/HOWTOs/Open-Portmapper-Services/open-Portmapper-services_node.html) you do it on Debian/Ubuntu) or at least block the access to the port 111/UDP via firewall.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Would i run these commands as normal queries in terminal through to the server? Please note that I am completely brand new to this stuff.

Comment: Basically the command you gave me: tcpdump -ni any udp
works on the terminal on my mac. How would i run that command for the amazon instance/server in which the problem exists?

Comment: As for 17, it is the number of lines of data you get in return for a short data request, which actually goes for the amplifying "feature".

Comment: After running rpcinfo -T udp without the "| wc -l" it gives me a list. Can you explain to me what this list is? Are they all portmappers?

Comment: Another question is: The server is an instance of Amazon's EC2/AWS service. IF you know anything about it, is there away for me to disable this port or would I have to contact amazon?